# Digital Signature field is not setting in PDF template using iTextpdf 5.5.13

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to set some fields in a from made by using adobe acrobat. I want that the finally generated PDF must contain the digital signature component as it is.

I want to achieve this using Java and itextpdf 5.5.13 jar.

Here is my code so far:

```
     //Getting PDF Reader
     PdfReader reader = null;
     //getting PDF Stamper
     PdfStamper stamper = null;
     //FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     try {
            String src = "D:\\workspace2\\runtime-EclipseApplication\\Project\\WebContent\\resources\\" +
                    "pdf_form_template\\invoice.pdf";

            reader = new PdfReader(src);
            stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(pdfPath));

            //Query and change fields in existing document by method calls.
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

            form.setField("contactNumber",phone_no);
            form.setField("name",name);
            form.setField("invoiceNumber",invoice_no);
            form.setField("GSTIN",gstin_no);
            form.setField("GSTIN_2",gstin_no);
            form.setField("Date","06/March/2019");
            form.setField("Ms",name);
            form.setField("Address 1",address);
            form.setField("Pin",pin_no);
            form.setField("State Code",state_code);
            form.setField("SNoRow1","1.");
            form.setField("Amount in Words",amount_in_words);
            form.setField("DESCRIPTIONRow1",desc);
            form.setField("HSN CODERow1",HSN_code);
            form.setField("AMOUNTTaxable Value", texable_value);
            form.setField("AMOUNTCGST 18", cgst_value);
            form.setField("AMOUNTSGST 9", sgst_value);
            form.setField("AMOUNTIGST 9", igst_value);
            form.setField("AMOUNTGRAND TOTAL", grand_total);

          //digital signature field in form template
            form.setField("digitalSignature","");

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    if (stamper != null) {

        try {
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
            stamper.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

The output pdf which I get contains all the fields that are set, except digital signature.

Answer (score 0):

setFormFlattening(true) is the reason why I'm getting a flattened pdf at last. 
Using partialFormFlattening is the correct way.